# Does "Superluminal travel of non-information" means we already "achieved" superluminal speeds?

Tags: causality, faster-than-light, information

From what I understood of [Vsauce video](https://youtu.be/JTvcpdfGUtQ) talking about "Superluminal travel of non-information," the absence of information **seems** to travel faster than the speed of light, since we perceive the absence of information **as** information.

Doesn't that mean that we can communicate faster than light using patterns of the absence of information? Like a shadow theatre?

Another example that it is shown in the video is the collision of two waves, where in the intersections of them in the middle can achieve the abstract concept of superluminal speeds.

Doesn't that mean that if we tune the wave pattern right, the intersection of the waves will travel faster, but carrying information by the viewer analyzing its pattern? Or it is already being used on normal communication systems?

I can imagine that it would be more of a one-way message, but still...

Comment: You should try and come up with a concrete proposal for how you'd utilize whatever mechanism you have in mind to superluminally tell your friend the result of a coin toss you do. You'd soon realize that it can't be done. :)

Comment: Patterns _are_ information. If you are able to communicate with somebody—by any means whatsoever—then you are sending them information.

Comment: VSauce explicitly spells out the answer that the question in the linked video. What is not clear about that answer?

Answer (score 6):

You can't encode non-information with information. The clue is in the name.

Take the example of shadow theater. I, at the projector, push a shadow across the screen with some angular velocity. The shadow propagates away from me at $c$ and across my field of view at $\omega r$. So, no message I encode in the shadow (really in *the end of my light pulse*) goes faster than light away from me.

You, standing at a screen at point $(r, \theta)$, can receive my signal, but there is nothing you can do to alter the shadow as it zips away from you across the screen possibly faster than light. The shadow is an indelible record of events in your past.

You could of course alter the end of the light pulse, using a prism or a mirror or a repeater, but that signal would be unrelated to the shadow and would propagate at $c$.

Answer (score 2):

> Doesn't that mean that we can communicate faster than light using patterns of the absence of information? Like a shadow theatre?

No.

> Doesn't that mean that if we tune the wave pattern right, the intersection of the waves will travel faster, but carrying information by the viewer analyzing its pattern? Or it is already being used on normal communication systems?

No.